# Gated Check-In rejected using Team Build 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I am trying to set-up a gated check-in using TFS/Team Build 2013.

It shelves the changes, runs the build successfully (this is a custom powershell script that right now does little more than write a few things to the console and return 0)

The build shows up as successful, however, if I inspect the build I can see it contains a failed Build Request that indicates the Check-in was rejected.

I have checked the build logs and cant see anything awry - it simply doesnt mention why the check-in was rejected

It may be worth noting that I am using a custom workflow(.xaml) file so perhaps there is something I need to do at the end in order to indicate everything is ok

[image: Team Build Screenshot]

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue with a similar customized template, and I do have the activities from the two answers in my template, and still the check-in is rejected upon a successful build.

Comment: Exact same situation 8 years later... Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the default workflow it has an activity at the end that checks in the Gated Changes.  It's wrapped in an InvokeForReason, so you need to also make sure your customizations aren't doing anything funky with the build reason, and also that you have this activity in your xaml.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove the MSBuild section since you are only running a script? If so make sure that you add those two section after you script run (if they are not present)

[image]

And make sure they are set to successful (if they are).  This is what "marks" the build successful or not.